# What's missing from my android eclipse installation?

Tags: android, eclipse

**I get this error, and previously it has been working nicely. But now it doesn't. What should I do?**

> [2012-08-01 09:18:08 - Dialog] ------------------------------
>
> [2012-08-01 09:18:08 - Dialog] Android Launch!
>
> [2012-08-01 09:18:08 - Dialog] adb is running normally.
>
> [2012-08-01 09:18:08 - Dialog] Could not find Dialog.apk!

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project before running it.

Go to Eclipse **Menu -> Project -> Clean**

Then try it again.